# How to use maven profiles and profiles in grails?

Tags: maven, grails, maven-profiles

I have grails application which is a subproject of a bigger maven project. I want to pass some properties to grails. The properties are defined in maven profiles. How can I do this?
How to access those properties in grails app? And how to use them if I want to run this app with grails run-app?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the maven Grails plugin.

Here is a sanitized excerpt of a working pom.xml where I successfully pass system properties to Grails:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
        <artifactId>grails-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${grails.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <properties>
            <java.io.tmpdir>${project.build.directory}</java.io.tmpdir>
          </properties>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks, how you access this property then?